# Changing the color of a button on click

Tags: android

Hi all I am making a project I want to change the button colour by pressing , for example suppose I press start button then it become red and when I press again it will become green. 
Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button buttonStart, buttonStop,buttonAddContact;
int button_status=1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        buttonAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
        onClickButtonListener();
    }


    public void onClickButtonListener () {
        buttonAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        buttonAddContact.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.abhishek.detector.Main22Activity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(button_status == 1)//play the service
        {
            button_status=0;
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
            startService(i);
        }
        else//stop the service
        {
            button_status=1;
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
            stopService(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `View.setBackgroundResource` to change the background color.

Comment: put your logcat error here......

Comment: error is relative to your service ......

Comment: but my service works fine before.

Comment: Will you post your full class code here ......

Comment: @SushilKumar ok ............

Comment: @help buttonStart, buttonStop,buttonAddContact in this which button you wanted to the change the color ?

Comment: button start.........

Comment: and please bind the buttonStop also like this.......   buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

Comment: yes the I delete that , I am working start and stop event by single start button..

Comment: which button you wanted to change background color ??  buttonStart,buttonAddContact ??

Comment: buttonstart...I want when I start service it become green and red on stop

Comment: Is you class running know ??

Comment: yes...................

Comment: please remove this line bcoz it is in no use .......
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: i have edit my answer please have look and tell me if any problem is there........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this global variable ........
inside your Activity and outside all methods

```
boolean flag = true;
```

and this is in your button click event..........

As Flag change it's value the color of button changes.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (flag) {
                arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                flag = true;
                 arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

    }
```

and try this class i edit your class for button color change ......

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        Button buttonStart,buttonAddContact;
   boolean flag = true;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            buttonAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
            buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
            onClickButtonListener();
        }


        public void onClickButtonListener () {
            buttonAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
            buttonAddContact.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.abhishek.detector.Main22Activity");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(flag)//play the service
            {
                flag=false;
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                startService(i);
                arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else//stop the service
            {
                flag=true;
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                stopService(i);
                arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
        }

    }
```

enjoy coding ...............

Comment: how do I use two if, else in one event?

Comment: sorry ?? please explain you problem ?

Comment: your answer is only for when I use a button without onclicklistner or any other event , but I am using a button to open activity to stop and start and I already used if else statement , so how can I use your if else in statement in mine , please check my on click event.

Comment: OP started chaining multiple and unrelated issues even though We edited his own codes rather than our custom solutions, so that I leaved, But you solved it anyway, +1 for your continuous effort.

Answer (score 1):

you can use selector to button as a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/green"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/red"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to change the color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

```
int count =0; //Declare this as class level variable so that you don't need to make it final

   myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(count==0){
            myBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            count++;
        }
        else{
            myBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE :**

Edited as per your codes,

```
int button_status=0; //Declare this as class level variable so that you don't need 

public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(button_status == 0)//play the service
        {
            button_status++;
            arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
            startService(i);
        }
        else//stop the service
        {
            button_status=0;
            arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
            stopService(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @help It's working fine on mine. there was one mistake that was `View.onClickListener`. And I fixed that as well. Now check it..

Comment: May be app crashed due to another reason. You can post crash log if you need more help.

Comment: That is really unrelated issue with this question bro, Just try if the solutions works or not by removing `startService` and `stopService` once. Then you can [Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) another question due to the issue with proper related codes.

Answer (score 0):

insert this file into drawable name button_color.xml
and then add this line in your button 
    android:background="@drawable/button_color"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     
<item android:state_pressed="true">
             
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                     
        <corners android:radius="8dip" />
                    
                     
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#39C6BD" android:startColor="#01F9F7" />
                   
                 
    </shape>
         
</item>
    
<item android:state_focused="true">
             
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                     
        <corners android:radius="8dip" />
                    
                     <solid android:color="#35D1C8" />      
                 
    </shape>
         
</item>
 
    
<item>      
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="8dip" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this save file name like btn_style.xml in drawable folder

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
```

btn_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_btn_bg_pressed_color" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_btn_bg_color" />
            <corners android:radius="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```